Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1) -- unable to install any new software, Software updater app crashes, too
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS several days ago from jammy and my software update app keeps jamming. I've run the commands
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt -fix --broken; sudo dpkg --configure -a

and lots of variations.
apt policy python3 is returning that I have 3.12.3 ubuntu installed, but the commands above are returning that numerous python programs are not installing and it seems to have something to do with dpkg.
I've tried the solutions at Dependency errors for python3 and many others when I run sudo apt-get upgrade to no effect.
In the time since I first made this post, my python-based programs have started working again, specifically gqrx and gnuradio, but when i run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade I still get a long return telling me that many python programs are not updated and I still get the dpkg error messages below. The Software Updater app opens and seems to work, but the Software & Updates app does not work.
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for  
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  freeglut3 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  libboost-regex1.74.0 libcupsfilters1 libflac8 libfontembed1 libgcab-1.0-0
  libicu70 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.5-0 libmessaging-menu0
  libmpdec3 libnautilus-extension1a libncurses-dev libnfs13 libosmocore18
  libosmogb12 libosmogsm17 libpcre3 libplist3 libpoppler118 libpython3.10
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28 libraw20 libsmbios-c2
  libsoup-gnome-2.4-1 libtiff5 libvpx7 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
693 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python3 (3.12.3-0ubuntu2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/externaltools/library.py:212: SyntaxWarn
ing: invalid escape sequence '\-'
  RE_KEY = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.\-]*)(\[([a-zA-Z_@]+)\])?$')
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/snippets/substitutionparser.py:162: Synt
axWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  match = re.match('\\\\?%s\s*' % self.REG_GROUP, tokens)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 55, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gobject-introspection
error running python rtupdate hook gobject-introspection
/usr/share/hplip/base/imagesize.py:186: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '
\#'
  re.compile('\#define\s+\S+\s+\d+')     : ('image/x-xbitmap', xbmsize),
/usr/share/hplip/base/imagesize.py:187: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '
\/'
  re.compile('\/\* XPM \*\/')            : ('image/x-xpixmap', xpmsize),
/usr/share/hplip/base/imagesize.py:189: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '
\*'
  re.compile('^II\*\x00')                : ('image/tiff', tiffsize),
/usr/share/hplip/fax/ledmfax.py:46: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
  http_result_pat = re.compile(b"""HTTP/\d.\d\s(\d+)""", re.I)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 55, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of libglib2.0-dev-bin
error running python rtupdate hook libglib2.0-dev-bin
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/alternative-toolbar/alttoolbar_plugins.py:171: Syntax
Warning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  translation = re.sub('\(..\)', '', translation, flags=re.DOTALL)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:64: SyntaxW
arning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  url = re.split('(\/display[^"]*)', entry)[1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:66: SyntaxW
arning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  title = re.split('(\/display[^>]*)([^<]*)', entry)[2][1:].strip()
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:97: SyntaxW
arning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  lyrics = re.split('(<font face=arial size=2>)(.*)(<\/font><br></td><td*)', res
ult)[2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/JetlyricsParser.py:50: Syntax
Warning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
  m = re.search('<a href=\'(http://jetlyrics\.com/viewlyrics\.php\?id=[0-9]*)\'>
', result)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/JlyricParser.py:49: SyntaxWar
ning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
  m = re.search('<div class=\'title\'><a href=\'(/artist/[^\.]*\.html)\'>', resu
lt)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/TerraParser.py:39: SyntaxWarn
ing: invalid escape sequence '\w'
  pattern = re.compile("&(#?\w+?);")
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/WinampcnParser.py:87: SyntaxW
arning: invalid escape sequence '\['
  lrcplaintext = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', lrcplaintext)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: 
invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\
([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-contextlib2:
 python3-contextlib2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-contextlib2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-common:
 sssd-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-proxy:
 sssd-proxy depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-opengl:
 python3-opengl depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not cNo apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written bec
ause the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. [This section repeats.]                                                                              

dpkg: error processing package python3-opengl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-freetype:
 python3-freetype depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-freetype (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-networkx:
 python3-networkx depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-networkx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   No apport rep
ort written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                 dependency pro
blems prevent configuration of python3-markupsafe:
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-markupsafe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sss:
 python3-sss depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-sss (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pythoNo apport report written
 because MaxReports is reached already
                                      No apport report written because MaxReport
s is reached already
                    n3-thrift:
 python3-thrift depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-thrift depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-thrift depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-thrift (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
[deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tz:
 python3-tz depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-fonttools:
 [same as earlier, deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-fonttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pyqt5-dev-tools:
 pyqt5-dev-tools depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 pyqt5-dev-tools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pyqt5-dev-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-fs:
 python3-fs depends on python3-tz; however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-fs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pil:amd64:
 python3-pil:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ipa:
 sssd-ipa depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cups:amd64:
 python3-cups:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cups:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cups:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tdb:
 python3-tdb depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
[deleted for space]
dpkg: error processing package python3-tdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pygments:
 python3-pygments depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-packaging:
[deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-packaging (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of gnuradio:
 gnuradio depends on python3-opengl; however:
  Package python3-opengl is not configured yet.
 gnuradio depends on python3-packaging; however:
  Package python3-packaging is not configured yet.
 gnuradio depends on python3-thrift; however:
  Package python3-thrift is not configured yet.
 gnuradio depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 gnuradio depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 gnuradio depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnuradio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-pil.imagetk:amd64:
 python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python3-pil (= 10.2.0-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.
 python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of bpfcc-tools:
 bpfcc-tools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bpfcc-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-jsonschema:
 python3-jsonschema depends on python3-importlib-resources | python3-supported-m
in (>> 3.9); however:
  Package python3-importlib-resources is not installed.
  Package python3-supported-min is not installed.
  Package python3 which provides python3-supported-min is not configured yet.
 python3-jsonschema depends on python3-typing-extensions | python3-supported-min
 (>> 3.8); however:
  Package python3-typing-extensions is not installed.
  Package python3-supported-min is not installed.
  Package python3 which provides python3-supported-min is not configured yet.
 python3-jsonschema depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-jsonschema (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of sssd-ad-common:
 sssd-ad-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-pyqt5.qwt:
 python3-pyqt5.qwt depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-pyqt5.qwt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-rlpycairo:
 python3-rlpycairo depends on python3-freetype; however:
 [deleted for space]
  
dpkg: error processing package python3-rlpycairo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5-common:
 sssd-krb5-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-zmq:
 python3-zmq depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-zmq depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-zmq depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-zmq (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-brotli:
 python3-brotli depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-brotli depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-brotli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of gr-osmosdr:
 gr-osmosdr depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 gr-osmosdr depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 gr-osmosdr depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gr-osmosdr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-cryptography:
 python3-cryptography depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-mdurl:
 python3-mdurl depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-mdurl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of libvolk-bin:
 libvolk-bin depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libvolk-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.12.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-cycler:
 python3-cycler depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cycler (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-kiwisolver:
 python3-kiwisolver depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-kiwisolver depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-kiwisolver depends on python3-typing-extensions | python3-supported-min
 (>= 3.8); however:
  Package python3-typing-extensions is not installed.
  Package python3-supported-min is not installed.
  Package python3 which provides python3-supported-min is not configured yet.
 python3-kiwisolver depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-kiwisolver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-brlapi:amd64:
 python3-brlapi:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-brlapi:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-brlapi:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-ldb:
 python3-ldb depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  [deleted for space]

dpkg: error processing package python3-ldb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-markdown:
 python3-markdown depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-markdown (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent configuration of python3-ufolib2:
 python3-ufolib2 depends on python3-fonttools (>= 4.29.1); however:
  Package python3-fonttools is not configured yet.
 python3-ufolib2 depends on python3-typing-extensions | python3-supported-min (>
= 3.8); however:
  Package python3-typing-extensions is not installed.
  Package python3-supported-min is not installed.
  Package python3 which provides python3-supported-min is not configured yet.
 python3-ufolib2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ufolib2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
 python3
 python3-contextlib2
 sssd-common
 sssd-proxy
 python3-opengl
 python3-freetype
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-networkx
 python3-markupsafe
 python3-sss
 python3-thrift
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 software-properties-common
 apport
 python3-tz
 python3-fonttools
 pyqt5-dev-tools
 python3-apport
 netplan.io
 python3-fs
 grub-common
 python3-pil:amd64
 sssd-ipa
 python3-cups:amd64
 python3-tdb
 python3-pygments
 python3-packaging
 python3-software-properties
 gnuradio
 python3-pil.imagetk:amd64
 bpfcc-tools
 python3-jsonschema
 sssd-ad-common
 python3-pyqt5.qwt
 python3-rlpycairo
 sssd-krb5-common
 python3-zmq
 python3-brotli
 gr-osmosdr
 python3-cryptography
 python3-mdurl
 libvolk-bin
 python3-dev
 python3-gi
 python3-cycler
 python3-kiwisolver
 python3-brlapi:amd64
 python3-ldb
 python3-markdown
 python3-ufolib2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Just want to add that the output is similar to the above when I use sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade: the output ends with, Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

While trying to run upgrades I've also gotten the following:    Could not install Python3 / The upgrade will continue but the python3 package may not be in a working state.  And then:  The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now. (dpkg --configure -a).  And then a notice that only a partial upgrade took place.

I've tried the recommendations posted here, but I've gotten the same results:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1522225/broken-dpkg-prevents-installing-python3-on-ubuntu-24-04  It's looking like I'll have to reinstall Ubuntu, I'm not sure of the significance of that, interested in any suggestions or insight.

$ apt install --reinstall python3-minimal python3.12-minimal -y
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
Then I try again with sudo -s and it runs through the whole output about dpkg and python3, ending as follows:   processing was halted because there were too many errors. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I am using a dual-boot environment with Windows on one partition and Ubuntu on a different partition.  Does that matter for reinstalling Ubuntu?  Ubuntu is on the primary partition.

My libre office programs won't open either; it's possible that the solution for that is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517385/libreoffice-packages-are-unconfigured-after-installing-and-wont-start?rq=1   but I'm not sure it matters if there are underlying python3 and dpkg problems.  Also, none of my python3-dependent programs survived the upgrade, although my files and other documents seem to be intact.  Any thoughts?

Please edit your question and add the results that you get when you run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Done; the return exceeded the space limit by about 3000 characters so I cut repetitive portions within paragraphs.

Try running steps 1 and 2 of this answer. If that doesn't work please comment and I will promptly reopen this question.

The response to step 1 was that "gnome-terminal is already the newest version, 3.52.0-1ubuntu2."  The response to step 2 was that "snap-store is already installed." When I run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, I still get the same response and it ends because "there were too many errors." Gnuradio is in the list of programs that it "encountered errors while processing," but my gnuradio programs are actually running just fine. The Software Updater app is telling me that the software is up to date.  As long as my python-based SDR programs are running, maybe the other issues don't matter?

I reopened your question following your patience and your reply.

In the output of your commands, sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, I see errors related to hplip:
error running python rtupdate hook gobject-introspection
/usr/share/hplip/base/imagesize.py:186: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '
\#'

...and rhythmbox:
error running python rtupdate hook libglib2.0-dev-bin
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/alternative-toolbar/alttoolbar_plugins.py:171: Syntax
Warning: invalid escape sequence '\('

It looks like this is associated with the following bug report:
SyntaxWarnings with Python3.12
Therefore, upgrade both hplip and rhythmbox first, and then do a full upgrade.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hplip rhythmbox


Just tried it, but received the same lengthy return as before, ending with "Processing was halted because there were too many errors. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"  In addition, there was a popup, "System program problem detected," asking me if I want to send a report, and when I sent a report, a second popup, "Sorry the application py3clean has stopped unexpectedly"   Does this last popup provide any insight into what the problem is?

I ran apt policy py3clean, and received, "Unable to locate package py3clean"   However, py3clean --version returns py3clean 3.12.3-0ubuntu2.

As for hplip and rhythmbox, the return after sudo apt install ... now includes, "hplip is already the newest version (3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5). rhythmbox is already the newest version (3.4.7-2ubuntu6)."
